# Using list() in my DRF view raises AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Wanted to convert my dictionary into a list inside of a django rest framework view using the list() built-in, but it raises `AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'META'.` Same if I try `.values()` or `.items()`. The error persists whether I put the dictionary in the `def list` method, or overwrite the `__init__` and put it there. Identical code outside of django seems to work fine, so what's going on here? Does it have something to do with the DRF method being named 'list'?
**Here is the simplified version that raises the error:**

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    some_dict = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    }

    def list(self, request, format=None):
        print(list(self.some_dict.keys()))
        return Response(some_response())
```

**And this works fine:**

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    some_dict = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    }

    def list(self, request, format=None):
        print(self.some_dict.keys())
        return Response(some_response())
```

Using [] instead of list() works, but it just puts the view object inside a list instead of converting it into one, so that's no good.
**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Github\MapPoolApp\MapPoolApp\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', include('mappool.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Github\MapPoolApp\mappool\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "E:\Github\MapPoolApp\mappool\views.py", line 188, in <module>
    class MapPoolViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  File "E:\Github\MapPoolApp\mappool\views.py", line 205, in MapPoolViewSet
    place = list(pool_args.items())
  File "E:\Github\MapPoolApp\mappool\views.py", line 49, in list
    return render(request, 'mappool/list.html', context)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 246, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "C:\Users\FluffyAdmin\.virtualenvs\MapPoolApp-gFHC46op\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py", line 40, in debug
    if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'META'
```

Is it some DRF magic or I'm missing something obvious here?

Comment: The error is not related to this `list(..)` itself, as you can see in the traceback.

Comment: Oh god, that's working with legacy code for you, scrolled up a few hundred lines and found a list() method, I was too focused to even consider this could be a thing. Thanks though.